# Actionmailer not working in rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the following config:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :user_name  => "sap@gmail.com",
  :password  => "sap"
}
```

When I send the mail, log shows mail is sent. I can see the mail in logger.

But, mail is not delivered to recipient email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just went through this myself.  If you're using ruby 1.8.6, you need to upgrade to 1.8.7 for it to work out of the box.  If not, you can try looking for action_mailer_tls off GitHub.