# ActionMailer Rails : Not able to send emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I have the following code in my environment/development.rb

```
 config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true;
 config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp;
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port => 587,
   :user_name => "my_id@gmail.com",
   :password => "secret",
   :authentication => :plain,
   :enable_starttls_auto => true,
   :domain => "localhost",
 }
```

An email is being generated by the call to the mailer model from one
of my controllers. However, i am not able to send or receive any
emails on gmail.

I am on ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.5.
There are no exceptions, just that no emails are being exchanged
between the actual mail servers.

Being quite new to mailer, sorry for any rookie questions.

A similar query:
[Actionmailer not working in rails 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514088/actionmailer-not-working-in-rails-2-3)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Above your code you you need to put those lines mandatory for the authentication:

```
require 'tlsmail'
Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
```

You need also the **tlsmail** gem.

If it doesn't work you can try removing the domain key from you settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing [authentication with STARTTLS before sending the mail](http://godbit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=876)?